# How to protect a fragment of code from auto-formatting CTRL+D in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is there any directive to prevent fragment of code from being changed?

For example:

```
procedure Test;
{CODE_FORMATTER OFF}
const  a1 = 'a';  a2 = 'b';  a3 = 'c';    
                  b2 = 'd';  b3 = 'e';

{CODE_FORMATTER ON}
begin
end;
```

Comment: No. You cannot protect it.

Comment: Your only option currently is to use a different code formatter. Both, the one in GExperts and the one in cnpack offer this option. And of course you could file a feature request with Embarcadero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any directive to prevent fragment of code from being changed?

No there is not.